# Firefox: How to disable "delete-key goes back"?

Tags: macos, keyboard, firefox

When I'm working in Firefox, I often accidentally <s>close a tab</s> go-back-in-history when I press the Delete key.

(For example, if I'm in Google Drive, and highlight a file, and then press Delete, the tab closes - instead of deleting the file!)

Is there a way to turn this off? I've dug through `about:config` and didn't see anything promising.

**Update:**
I made a mistake in my original question: Firefox is going *back* when I hit Delete, not closing the tab.

Comment: good question, I have that problem to. Sadly it looks like one has to install some add on like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saka-key/?src=search to do that, which I am hesitant to do.

Comment: The delete key (forward or backward) doesn't normally close the current tab? Is this issue caused by some add-on?

Comment: Same as Alexander, the Delete key doe not close a tab or window for me, and it never has as I recall. There may be a config on your computer that is changing the behavior of delete in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I realized it was "go back" instead of "close tab" - the answer can be found [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1202555):

> You can set this pref to 2 on the about:config page to disable the
>   backspace_action. `browser.backspace_action = 2`